# Report generation on Assert failure

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to generate report if assert fails in webdriver test.
But problem is whenever assert fails ,report is not generated by log4j.
Can someone please suggest how to resolve it.
I am using maven,junit4,java and webdriver.

Thanks

Comment: You question is too vague, how exactly do you want to create the report?And what testing framework you have - TestNG, JUnit?

Comment: Framework-Junit4 Suppose test fail at any assert then cause of failure should be written in log4j report